# is there a way of changing print margins using gecko c#

Tags: c#, gecko

I'm trying to create a simple app that prints from a webpage, which needs to print on thermal paper with no margins. however some of the GeckoPreferences don't seem to do anything unlike the about:config built into firefox

```
GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_edge_left"] = 0;
GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_edge_right"] = 0;
GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_edge_top"] = 0;
GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_edge_bottom"] = 0;

GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_unwriteable_margin_left"] = 0;
GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_unwriteable_margin_right"] = 0;
GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_unwriteable_margin_top"] = 0;
GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_unwriteable_margin_bottom"] = 0;

GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_margin_left"] = 0;
GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_margin_right"] = 0;
GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_margin_top"] = 0;
GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_margin_bottom"] = 0;
```

Iv also tried these using print.printer_PrinterName and that doesn't change anything either, any help would be appreciated. I'm not a massively experienced dev so an explanation why would be great also

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i was supposed to use a string instead of an int...

```
GeckoPreferences.User["print.printer_PrinterName.print_margin_bottom"] = "0";
GeckoPreferences.User["print.printer_PrinterName.print_margin_left"] = "0";
GeckoPreferences.User["print.printer_PrinterName.print_margin_right"] = "0";
GeckoPreferences.User["print.printer_PrinterName.print_margin_top"] = "0";
```

Oh well, live and learn